# Proving a binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Prove that ($k\le m$)

$$\sum_{j=k}^m(_{2m+1}^{2j+1})(_k^j)=\frac{2^{2(m-k)}(2m-k)!}{(2m-2k)!k!} , (k\le m)$$

Please help me with this identity, I've spent a lot of time on it but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your question seems wrong. If sum is from k to m, then only the 1st term j=k will be computed for when j=k+1, then the 2nd binomial coefficient will not exist.

Comment: Thank you, it's my mistake, i've corrected the identity

Comment: The binomial coefficient on the LHS should be $\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OPs expression we show:

> The following is valid
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=k}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}\binom{j}{k}=4^{m-k}\binom{2m-k}{k}\qquad\qquad 0\leq k \leq m
> \end{align*}

In the following we use the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^{k}$ in a series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^j$.

> We start with the left hand side and transform the sum into a coefficient of $x^k$ of a polynomial in $x$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=k}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}\binom{j}{k}&=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}\binom{j}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}(1+x)^j\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we start the index $j$ from $0$. Note that $\binom{j}{k}=0$ if $j<k$. We also write $\binom{j}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^j$.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.

Note, that (2) contains binomial coefficients with *odd* $2j+1$. We consider $(1\pm y)^{2m+1}$ and split it into odd and even parts.
\begin{align*}
(1\pm y)^{2m+1}&=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j}y^{2j}\pm \sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}y^{2j+1}\\
\end{align*}

> We get
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}y^{2j}=\frac{(1+y)^{2m+1}-(1-y)^{2m+1}}{2y}
> \end{align*}
>
> Substituting: $y\rightarrow\sqrt{1+x}$ we obtain from (2)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=k}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}\binom{j}{k}
> =[x^k]\frac{(1+\sqrt{1+x})^{2m+1}-(1-\sqrt{1+x})^{2m+1}}{2\sqrt{1+x}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Note, the expression on the RHS is a *polynomial*, since the factor $\sqrt{1+x}$ cancels out.

Next we transform the RHS of OPs expression. We consider it as coefficient of the polynomial

> \begin{align*}
> 4^{m-k}\binom{2m-k}{k}&=4^{m-k}[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m-k}{k}x^{j}\\
> &=4^m[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m-k}{k}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^{j}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

In order to prove (4) we refer to a useful identity stated as formula (2.1) in H.W.Goulds *[Combinatorial Identities, Vol. 4](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.4.PDF)*. With $n=2m+1$ we get the following expression

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^j\binom{2m-j}{j}(t_1t_2)^j(t_1+t_2)^{2m-2j}=\frac{t_1^{2m+1}-t_2^{2m+1}}{t_1-t_2}
\end{align*}

> Setting $t_1=1+\sqrt{1+x}$ and $t_2=1-\sqrt{1+x}$ we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> t_1t_2&=-x\\
> t_1+t_2&=2\\
> t_1-t_2&=2\sqrt{1+x}
> \end{align*}
>
> It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m-j}{j}x^j2^{2m-2j}
> =\frac{(1+\sqrt{1+x})^{2m+1}-(1-\sqrt{1+x})^{2m+1}}{2\sqrt{1+x}}
> \end{align*}
>   and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 4^{m-k}\binom{2m-k}{k}=[x^k]\frac{(1+\sqrt{1+x})^{2m+1}-(1-\sqrt{1+x})^{2m+1}}{2\sqrt{1+x}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

The RHS of (3) and (5) coincide and OPs identity follows.

Comment: (+1). I have just contributed a proof that uses a slightly different set of generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to show that
$$\sum_{q=k}^m {2m+1\choose 2q+1} {q\choose k}
= 4^{m-k} {2m-k\choose k}.$$

Introduce
$${2m+1\choose 2q+1} = {2m+1\choose 2m-2q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-2q+1}}
(1+z)^{2m+1} \; dz.$$

This has the property that it is zero when $q\gt m$ so it controls the
range and we may extend the sum to infinity to obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m+1}}
(1+z)^{2m+1}
\sum_{q\ge k} {q\choose k} z^{2q} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m+1}}
(1+z)^{2m+1} z^{2k}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+k\choose k} z^{2q} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-2k+1}}
(1+z)^{2m+1}
\frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{k+1}}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-2k+1}}
(1+z)^{2m-k}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
\; dz.$$

Extracting the coefficient we get

$$\sum_{q=0}^{2m-2k} {2m-k\choose q} {2m-2k-q+k\choose k}
= \sum_{q=0}^{2m-2k} {2m-k\choose q} {2m-k-q\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{2m-2k} {2m-k\choose 2m-k-q} {2m-k-q\choose k}.$$

This is
$$\sum_{q=0}^{2m-2k} {2m-k\choose k} {2m-2k\choose q}
\\ = {2m-k\choose k} \sum_{q=0}^{2m-2k} {2m-2k\choose q}
\\ = 2^{2m-2k} {2m-k\choose k}$$

as claimed.

Comment: Nice  and straight forward! :-)  I appreciate your approach.+1

Comment: The two factorials $(2m-k-q)!$ cancel and are replaced by two copies of $(2m-2k)!.$ Expand the binomial coefficients into factorials to see what is going on.

Comment: I see! Thanks! :-)